# ProxyRemote works with HTTP URL but not with HTTPS

Tags: apache, ssl, proxy, httpd.conf, mod-proxy

ProxyRemote Directive doesn't work with HTTPS:

```
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName foo.foo

    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    #SSLProxyVerifyDepth 10
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    # SAAS: disable hostname check
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

    SSLProxyCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/


    ProxyRemote * https://10.27.73.178:443/
    ProxyPass /api/ https://foo.gw.dev/api/
    ProxyPassReverse /api/ https://foo.gw.dev/api/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /storage/user/conf/ssl/web_cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /storage/user/conf/ssl/web_key.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /storage/user/conf/ssl/web_chain.pem


    SSLCACertificatePath /storage/user/conf/ssl/
    SSLVerifyClient none
    </VirtualHost>
```

It works if I specify http URL, like

```
    ProxyRemote * http://10.27.73.178:3128/
```

I think it is a certificate checking issue, where exactly should I specify the proxy CA certificate?

I get the following error logs:

```
[Wed Nov 27 14:35:40.961981 2019] [proxy_http:trace1] [pid 32633:tid 140286441285376] mod_proxy_http.c(1931): [client 127.0.0.1:54302] HTTP: serving URL https://foo.gw.dev/api/
[Wed Nov 27 14:35:40.961989 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 32633:tid 140286441285376] proxy_util.c(2302): AH00942: HTTPS: has acquired connection for (foo.gw.dev)
[Wed Nov 27 14:35:40.961993 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 32633:tid 140286441285376] proxy_util.c(2355): [client 127.0.0.1:54302] AH00944: connecting https://foo.gw.dev/api/ to foo.gw.dev:443
[Wed Nov 27 14:35:40.962067 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 32633:tid 140286441285376] proxy_util.c(2564): [client 127.0.0.1:54302] AH00947: connected /api to 10.27.73.178:443
[Wed Nov 27 14:35:40.962086 2019] [proxy:trace2] [pid 32633:tid 140286441285376] proxy_util.c(2999): HTTPS: fam 2 socket created to connect to foo.gw.dev
[Wed Nov 27 14:35:41.172521 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 32633:tid 140286441285376] proxy_util.c(3033): AH02824: HTTPS: connection established with 10.27.73.178:443 (foo.gw.dev)
[Wed Nov 27 14:35:41.172570 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 32633:tid 140286441285376] proxy_util.c(2660): AH00948: CONNECT: sending the CONNECT request for foo.gw.dev:443 to the remote proxy 10.27.73.178:443 (10.27.73.178)
[Wed Nov 27 14:35:41.383758 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 32633:tid 140286441285376] (104)Connection reset by peer: AH00958: HTTPS: attempt to connect to foo.gw.dev:443 via http CONNECT through 10.27.73.178:443 (foo.gw.dev) failed
[Wed Nov 27 14:35:41.383798 2019] [proxy_http:error] [pid 32633:tid 140286441285376] [client 127.0.0.1:54302] AH01114: HTTP: failed to make connection to backend: 10.27.73.178
[Wed Nov 27 14:35:41.383802 2019] [proxy:debug] [pid 32633:tid 140286441285376] proxy_util.c(2317): AH00943: HTTPS: has released connection for (foo.gw.dev)
```

Comment: *"...doesn't work..."* is not a useful error description. Please provide the exact errors you get. You will likely find more errors in the error log of your server.

Comment: It just says that it failed to connect. Doesn't contain any information about the details that's why I don't know how to fix it. My understanding is that it is related to certificate validation. So, I guess I have to figure out how to make certificate validation work. I've checked my proxy server separately with curl and it works.

Comment: Again: *"You will likely find more errors in the error log of your server."*

Comment: This is the error in my proxy side : 1574785873.047      0 10.92.167.252 NONE/000 0 NONE error:transaction-end-before-headers - HIER_NONE/- -

And this is the error on my apache server: [Wed Nov 27 07:39:26.102668 2019] [proxy:error] [pid 17477:tid 140499671258880] (104)Connection reset by peer: AH00958: HTTPS: attempt to connect to foo.gw.dev:443 via http CONNECT through 10.27.73.178:443 (foo.gw.dev) failed

Comment: "where exactly should I specify the proxy CA certificate?" - `SSLProxyCACertificatePath` (resp. `"File`) sounds good! (is it available/valid at this place?)

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxycacertificatepath: " ...The files in this directory have to be PEM-encoded and are accessed through hash filenames. So usually you can't just place the Certificate files there: you also have to create symbolic links named hash-value.N. And you should always make sure this directory contains the appropriate symbolic links."